# How to flatten bigquery record with multiple repeated fields?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to query against app-engine datastore backup data.  In python, the entities are described as something like this:

```
class Bar(ndb.Model):
    property1 = ndb.StringProperty()
    property2 = ndb.StringProperty()

class Foo(ndb.Model):
    bar = ndb.StructuredProperty(Bar, repeated=True)
    baz = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Unfortunately when `Foo` gets [backed up and loaded into bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-cloud-datastore), the table schema gets loaded as:

```
bar             |  RECORD  |  NULLABLE
bar.property1   |  STRING  |  REPEATED
bar.property2   |  STRING  |  REPEATED
baz             |  STRING  |  NULLABLE
```

What I would like to do is to get a table of all `bar.property1` and associated `bar.property2` where `baz = 'baz'`.

Is there a simple way to flatten `Foo` so that the bar records are "zipped" together?  If that's not possible, is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted in a comment by @Mosha, it seems that big query supports User Defined Functions (UDF).  You can input it in the `UDF Editor` tab on the web UI.  In this case, I used something like:

```
function flattenTogether(row, emit) {
  if (row.bar && row.bar.property1) {
    for (var i=0; i < row.bar.property1.length; i++) {
      emit({property1: row.bar.property1[i],
            name: row.bar.property2[i]});
    }
  }
};

bigquery.defineFunction(
  'flattenBar',
  ['bar.property1', 'bar.property2'],
  [{'name': 'property1', 'type': 'string'},
   {'name': 'property2', 'type': 'string'}],
  flattenTogether);
```

And then the query looked like:

```
SELECT
  property1,
  property2,
FROM
  flattenBar(
  SELECT
    bar.property1,
    bar.property2,
  FROM
    [dataset.foo]
  WHERE
    baz = 'baz')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since baz is not repeated, you can simply filter on it in WHERE clause without any flattening:

```
SELECT bar.property1, bar.property2 FROM t WHERE baz = 'baz'
```

Comment: I get `Error: Cannot output multiple independently repeated fields at the same time.`

Comment: Could you set query option "Flatten Results" to false

Comment: Not without setting an output table (at least not in the web UI) -- Which isn't really desirable for ad-hoc  queries over the data.

Comment: Yes, not flattening requires destination table. So either you use Javascript TVF to zip these fields together, or ask separately why loading datastore backup made them intepedently repeated, and not created bar as repeated record instead.

Comment: Awesome.  The Javascript UDF seems to be working.  I'll write that up as an answer for posterity.  (I feel like I can't be the only one with this problem)...